# Is it possible to connect Power BI Report to a Shared Data Source in the Power BI Report Server (on-premises)

Tags: powerbi, sql-server-2016, power-bi-report-server

I have a report (.pbix file) successfully deployed to Power BI Report Server and I want to connect it to a Shared Data Source I've created (as I always do when I deploy SSRS reports) independently, but I do not see any possibility to do that...

It seems like there is only option to use embedded data sources and configure them all separately for Power BI reports.

Is it true or I just haven't figure it out?

**Data Source**

[image]

**Report**

[image]

Comment: What kind of "Shared Data Source" are you referring to? You can definitely link to SQL servers or shared network drives.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've added a picture to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, it is not possible to connect a Power BI report to a shared data source like you're hoping. I had the same hopes, but I guess Microsoft hasn't gotten there yet.

See: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Shared-data-Source/m-p/175620/highlight/true#M76987

Comment: That's nice. I mean pity :) Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Although it is fairly straight forward with Power BI Service (PowerBI.com), it is not the case with Power BI Report Server, running on premise.

There is a feature request that remains 'declined' so far, on the Power BI Idea site.

This link should be helpful.

[Shared data source connection (live to Tabular SSAS) for reports published on Power BI Report Server](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=3f3c572b-2f0a-4f77-9381-35a59b4cc1cc)